# Can't scroll my ListView inside fragment

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments, android-listview

I have a fragment that must be one of layouts inside a viewPager. And my fragment has a listView that should be filled with some constant texts.
just like below:

```
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    Display_Rows();
}

private void Display_Rows() {
    Log.d(TAG, "Displaying Rows...");

    final ListView lv =(ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.Asset_Scanned_listView);
    final List<String> lst = new ArrayList<String>();

    lst.add("1");
    lst.add("2");
    lst.add("3");
    lst.add("4");
    lst.add("5");
    lst.add("6");
    lst.add("7");
    lst.add("8");
    lst.add("9");
    lst.add("10");

    ArrayAdapter<String> ArAd =new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,lst);

    lv.setAdapter(ArAd);                
    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(){
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,int arg2, long arg3){
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), String.valueOf(((TextView)arg1).getText()), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }});

    Log.d(TAG, "Rows Displayed");
}
```

This is part of my xml:

```
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/RLayoutSort"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/Asset_Scanned_listView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    </ListView>

</ScrollView>
```

But my listView is showing only first text. Can anyone help me what is wrong in my code?

Comment: What does your view look like? Please paste your layout as I suspect that is the issue.

Comment: If your `ListView` s height fixed or `wrap_content`?

Comment: Change `Height` and `width` of `ScrollView` to `match_parent`.

Comment: @PiYusHGuPtA not height(height should be wrap_content only) only width.

Comment: I can't put image here(more reputation required).

Comment: Problem is not height.if so scroll should appeare

Comment: The problem was here:
 **No need for ScrollView!**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Genius Try this

1. You should add the list view values in the **[onStart()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onStart%28%29)** or **[onActivityCreated()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#onActivityCreated%28android.os.Bundle%29)** in your fragment.

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment()).commit();
    }
}

/**
 * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
 */
public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

    /**
     * Declare ListView .
     */
    ListView lv;

    public PlaceholderFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);

        /**
         * Inititlize.
         */
        lv = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.listView);

        return rootView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

        List<String> lst = new ArrayList<String>();
        for(int i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
            lst.add(i + "");
        }

        ArrayAdapter<String> ArAd = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, lst);
        lv.setAdapter(ArAd);

    }

}

 }
```

**fragment_main.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:background="#e5e5e5"
    tools:context="com.example.app.MainActivity$PlaceholderFragment" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView"
        android:textColor="#FF0000"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:dividerHeight="1dp"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**Result is**

[image]

Comment: Thanks Professor but my problem was not that. It was an example and For clause is not important. may problem is the ScrollView that is not scrolling.

Answer (score 2):

Set your `ScorllView`

```
android:layout_width="match_parent"
```

As parent of your `ListView` is not `match_parent` or `fill_parent` so your `ListView` will not be with full width.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

**main.xml**

```
 <ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:gravity="center" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/Asset_Scanned_listView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#FFFFFF"
        android:cacheColorHint="#374c0e"
        android:divider="#004466"
        android:dividerHeight="1dp"
        android:listSelector="#99ddff" >
    </ListView>
</ScrollView>
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
.......

public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

    /**
     * Declaration.
     */
    List<String> lst;
    ListView listView;
    private String TAG = "MainAcitivity";

    public PlaceholderFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container,
                false);

        listView = (ListView) rootView
                .findViewById(R.id.Asset_Scanned_listView);
        return rootView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

        Display_Rows();

    }

    private void Display_Rows() {

        Log.d(TAG, "Displaying Rows...");

        List<String> lst = new ArrayList<String>();
        lst.add("1");
        lst.add("2");
        lst.add("3");
        lst.add("4");
        lst.add("5");
        lst.add("6");
        lst.add("7");
        lst.add("8");
        lst.add("9");
        lst.add("10");

        ArrayAdapter<String> ArAd = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, lst);

        listView.setAdapter(ArAd);

        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                    int arg2, long arg3) {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(),
                        String.valueOf(((TextView) arg1).getText()),
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

        Log.d(TAG, "Rows Displayed");
    }
}
  }
```

**Result is**

[image]